# Jacoco report interpretation

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco

We are trying Jacoco for functional code coverage. We are able to create coverage  report using Jacoco. However not able to interpret it properly

Generally it shows the codes covered during execution in one color (here yellow) and not covered in another color (here red). But there are some codes in the same class which is not covered in either of the color.

What does this means? Are these lines of code touched during execution or not?

Answer (score 4):

See here: what color means.
http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/annotations.html

and

http://www.eclemma.org/faq.html#trouble02

I see Jacoco by design ignores any comments (single/multiline), class definitions, opening brackets, variable definitions/declarations, imports in Java/Groovy etc, etc as they are not considered as actual "executable" code.

Somehow Lists, map variable type definitions and blank funcations/methods brackets/braces are shown as covered.